# R programming: Dataframe Subset Returning Inconsistent Results

Tags: r

I am having this problem in R.  I have been scratching my head for 2 days.

If a did

```
list.of.genes.common.to.Group1.and.Group2<-intersect(Group1df, Group2df)

a <- unlist(list.of.genes.common.to.Group1.and.Group2)

#if I don't unlist, then I get nothing

b <- Group1df[rownames(Group1df) %in% a,]

c <- Group2df[rownames(Group2df) %in% a,]
```

dimensions of b and c are NOT the same, yet the list a was generated from the length of the list common to both...

b is about 200 short and c is about 300 short.

What is the deal?

Comment: Can you share a small, sample dataset? It's hard to tell without knowing the structure of your data.

Comment: This code does not seem to make sense.  Did you mean `list.of.genes.common.to.Group1.and.Group2<-intersect(rownames(Group1df), rownames(Group2df))`  ?